# Fantasy book series about teenage kids with magical abilities travelling across a land to meet and defeat an evil entity

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, magic

I’m trying to remember the title of a book series I started reading in the late '90s/very early 2000s. I’d read the first one or two of the four(?) in the series.

From what I can remember, teenage kids who possessed specific magical abilities were being escorted by skilled fighters of sorts across a land with beasts and individuals trying to kill them. Their destination was to meet and defeat an evil entity (sorceress?). As they got closer, their powers grew.

A specific scene I remember is a part where they get help from mythical miners to tunnel through a mountain and encounter a monster worm. Another is where they are attacked and, as arrows are about to hit one teen, the other turns the arrows into flowers and they are showered in petals.

Any help tracking the books down would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that arrows -> flowers is a classic trope; it appears in Hindu myths and Buddhist teachings.

Comment: This vaguely sounds like "His dark materials" or "Dune". Do you have any other clue? How many kids? Were there adults?